# How to Convert Date Format in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

how to convert Fri Jul 19 2019 00:00:00 GMT 0800 (Singapore Standard Time) this format to mysql date format using PHP?
I tried to use strtotime but none of them working for me

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("Fri Jul 19 2019 00:00:00 GMT 0800 (Singapore Standard Time)"));
```

Comment: The date fails to parse due to `Double timezone specification` (from the PHP error).

Comment: Do you control the formatting of the date?

Comment: I'm not controlling the format of the date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date fails to parse because it's in a very weird format.

If you can't control the format of the incoming date you could grab the different parts using regex and parse them:

```php
$rawDate = "Fri Jul 19 2019 00:00:00 GMT 0800 (Singapore Standard Time)";
preg_match('/(.*?) GMT (\d+)\s\(.*?\)/', $rawDate, $matches);

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M j Y H:i:s', $matches[1])
   ->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('+' . $matches[2]));

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // outputs 2019-07-19 06:00:00
```

Example: https://3v4l.org/fbuMk